# Non Dell memory in a PowerEdge 1850

Tags: memory, dell, dell-poweredge

Would it be acceptable to install compatible RAM from a non Dell manufacturer?  Specifically I am wondering if it is OK to install HP PC2-5300P ECC memory into a PowerEdge 1850?  The part number for the memory I am thinking of purchasing is: 408853-B21.

Comment: I might be slightly concerned if you are heavily concerned about vendor support for the equipment.  It seems unlikely, but Dell might get really annoyed at you if you request support and the problem turns out to be related to that memory.  But if you only have the basic support, or your system is no longer supported, then it it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the RAM is compatible, of the same speed and specification and physically fits, you should be fine.

Comment: +1 - I'll buy RAM from Crucial since they'll guarantee compatibility and have a lifetime warranty. They're not the cheapest, but they're much less than OEM.